# Example of connecting http gateway server to name server of Python Pyro

Tags: python-3.x, pyro4

As a beginner in Python and programming, can you guys give me a code or provide the steps for the example of connecting http gateway server with name server in Python Pyro5 or Pyro4? I tried searching and tried couple of things by reading the doc https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tipstricks.html#http-gateway, but it's unclear to me on how to make it work.
I'm using Python37-32 in windows7 env.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [http](https://github.com/irmen/Pyro4/tree/master/examples/http) example from Pyro4 (or the same from Pyro5 if you're using that). It shows a working setup.